# How to save an image from http client to a specific folder in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a small function that will save an image from an http client but I have 2 issues.

1. The image is being saved in the bin folder and I have a folder in the project that I created called photos that I want the code to save in.
2. I want to get 8 more images and not overwrite the current image as another call will rewrite the image. My code is as below, the different ids will give the different images:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url+id))
    {
        request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
        using (
            Stream contentStream = await (await httpClient.SendAsync(request)).Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(),
            stream = new FileStream("test", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            await contentStream.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

So the result has been a file called test but overwrites the previous one. I want to save all of them and save in a folder in the project. How would I go about this? Any suggestions are welcome, thanks.

Comment: Try chaanging the filename from `"test"` to something like `$"test {id}"`.

Comment: There is no concept of a "project" when the compiled app runs.

Answer (score 0):

## 1.

Doing `new FileStream("test", ...)` will open a new filestream at `.\test` which isn't what we want, as `.` is the directory in which you program is being executed. Instead any and all application data should go into the `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData\YourApplicationName` so:

```cs
var photoLocation = Path.Combine(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData, "MyUwpApp", "Photos", "test");

// Ensure %AppData%\MyUwpApp\Photos exists, if not create it
if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(photoLocation))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(photoLocation));

stream = new FileStream(photoLocation, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
```

You could place the check for if the directory exists or not outside of the loop, to only check it once. But then your program could crash if `Photos` or `MyUwpApp` get deleted during the loop. You could also save the return value of `Path.GetDirectoryName(photoLocation)` if you really wanted to, to avoid having to call it twice.

## 2.

You need unique file names. The easiest way to do it is append the `id` to each file, like Roy Cohen said in their comment:

```cs
var photoLocation = Path.Combine(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData, "MyUwpApp", "Photos", "test", id.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you, however when I run this I get a permission denied error to the path that I have provided.

Comment: @Megatron213 you could declare [broadFileSystemAccess capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#example) in package.appxmainfest.This is a restricted capability.  Access is configurable in **Settings** > **Privacy** > **File system**.